# how to use selenium locate inpurt element after a specific text with python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

for some reason

I need to input some text after the 'Test'
but the input name will always auto change with different name and even some different format , so I can't locate it via a fixed CSS or Xpath

```
<tr class="123"><td class="456">
<div class="789">Test</div></td><td><input size="16" maxlength="15" name="ABC"></td>
```

i try to locate via xpath like this

```
//*[descendant::*[contains(text(),'Test')]]/input[1]
```

but fail .. I thought I should do in wrong way , help....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An XPath to locate the input following the text "Test":

```
"//div[.='Test']/following::input[1]"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `following-sibling` axis like this :

```
//td[div='Test']/following-sibling::td[1]/input
```